# $.post not sending data to php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Okay I am at a loss for what is going wrong. I am trying to pass the form data to my php script from a simple jQuery script but for some reason when I try to access $_POST data php says that $_POST is empty?

Here we go, so I have the following jQuery and php scripts

jQuery

```
var post = $('#cform').serialize();
console.log("POST DATA: " + post);
$.post(action, post, function(data){
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
    $('#message').slideDown('slow');
    $('#cform img.contact-loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    if(data.match('success') != null) $('#cform').slideUp('slow');
 });
```

PHP

```
$fname  = $_POST['fname'];
$lname  = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
```

The console log of var post looks like this

```
POST DATA: fname=Daniel&lname=Jarvis&email=test%40gmail.com&phone=4444444444&comments=hello
```

And the var_dump of $_POST says this

```
array(0) { }
```

I have no clue why this is giving me so many problems so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S**
I have also tried simply doing this for the post data but it still was not working.

```
var post = {fname: $('#fname').val(), lname: $('lname').val(), ...} //you get the idea
```

The console.log looked like this

```
{fname: "Dan", lname: "Jarvis", ...}
```

But when I var_dumped the $_POST variable it still said

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: Look into the `$.ajax()` syntax. Its much more intuitive than the `$.post()` syntax in my opinion.

Comment: check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. if that's not saying post, then your ajax post got redirected somewhere else.

Comment: Watch the request / response in the browser's console. You will see if the request contains the payload and any data returned by the response.

Comment: I looked at the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and it says string(3) "GET"? Any ideas what that means or why it is saying GET and not POST? @MarcB

Comment: something cause your post to get redirected, which turned it into a get. you'll have to dig around for rewrites or other server-side shenanigans.

Comment: Try using `$.ajax` method instead

Comment: @Umair I actually started out using $.ajax but that was not working either so I started using this $.post method. I think is right it is some weird redirect thingy I got going on I have not clue how to debug this though so if you guys have any ideas on that feel free to help a brother out ;) Thanks for all the help you guys!

Comment: Is there an .htaccess file on your site doing rewrites?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nope, I actually just set the site up so I have not made a .htacess file that would effect this particular folder yet. I do have varnish cache running in front of apache but I have never had it mess with any of my ajax requests before so I don't know but maybe that might be doing something funny to my request?

Comment: I can't be sure, but I would take everything out of the equation until this shakes out.

Comment: You know the funny thing is if I use $.get for the Ajax request everything works fine. I can access the data I am passing in the php script via $_GET but for some reason $.post just does not want to cooperate. Would it be wrong if I sent contact form data over get? @JayBlanchard

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Alright I guess I will just let it like that then. Problem solved. Thanks a lot man! @JayBlanchard

Comment: Did u solve issue? what was problem?

Comment: @Umair No I couldn't get $.post to work for some reason so my solution was just to use $.get instead. I literally just changed $.post to $.get in the .js file and changed $_POST['...'] to $_GET['...'] in the .php file and everything works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ahhh okay .. but those variables sent are supposed to be in POST array :P BTW are u using any framework?

Comment: @Umair yeah that is exactly why I started off trying to get $.post to work I am not actually using a framework this site was supposed to be super simple so I just have the jquery.min file and this was in a contact.js file. Do you think a framework might help?

Answer (score 0):

*There are several issues in your code,

1.Add event which will trigger ajax.

2.Your php script does not echo any data.

3.No return false or prevent defaul to stop form submission manually.(I think this is the main issue)

check the solution:*

**HTML:**

```
    <form id="form">

    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <input type="text" name="comments">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

    </form>

    <span id="message"></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $("#form").submit(function(){

        var post = $('#form').serialize();
        console.log("POST DATA: " + post);
        $.post('target.php', post, function(data){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown('slow');
        $('#cform img.contact-loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        if(data.match('success') != null) $('#cform').slideUp('slow');

     });
    return false;
    })
```

**PHP(I assume that your php script is target.php):**

```
  $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname  = $_POST['lname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $comments = $_POST['comments']; 

  echo $fname.$lname.$email.$phone.$comments;
```

Comment: 1. The question doesn't show how the ajax is being triggered, but it clearly is because the output of the function has been described. 2. The OP has quoted what they see when they put `var_dump` in the PHP, so it does output data, it just isn't expressed well in the question. 3. That presupposes that a form submission is being used to triggered the submission … since the question quotes the output of the PHP, it probably isn't the issue.

Comment: @Quentin his php script is not receiving any data thats why var_dump() showing empty array. because ajax is not sending any data using post. Ajax is sending data using get because of not using `return false`. The form submission is performing manually so the get is sending data. And how you can say that his php script is sending data? He is not using any echo at all. and where is the event which will trigger the code?

Comment: "Ajax is sending data using get because of not using return false. " — That doesn't make any sense at all. "The form submission is performing manually so the get is sending data" — That's an interesting theory, but the question doesn't have enough information in it to be sure that is the case. "And how you can say that his php script is sending data? He is not using any echo at all" — Because the OP has showed the `var_dump` code they are using and what it outputs. "where is the event which will trigger the code" — Not in the question, but since the code **is** triggered …

Comment: @Quentin if i do not set the method for a form and submit the form manually what will be the method? Absolutely `GET`. So how can $_POST method grab data from get? and What will `var_dump` do then? var_dump will send no data.